# Sluggish cursor with usb-mouse connected through dongle MBA M1

Tags: usb, mouse, video-adapter

I have a new MBA-M1 with the [Anker 8 in 1 dongle](https://us.anker.com/products/a8383). I currently have plugged to it the following devices simultaneously: 1) HDMI for my 1080p monitor, 2) USB-A for keyboard, 3) USB-A for backup external disk, and 4) USB-A for USB wireless mouse (I don't know the technical name of it, but is a wireless mouse that is connected with the computer through a USB-A dongle which comes with the mouse).

Now, 1, 2 and 3 work good simultaneously, but the wireless mouse (4) performs very poorly, as the cursor is very sluggish and has a lot of lag relative to the actual mouse movements. I tried disconnecting the other devices at once and testing how it worked out, turns out that going without the external monitor connection (HDMI) brings back to normal the behavior of the mouse. Nonetheless it's not feasible for me having to choose between mouse or monitor. Then, I'd be very grateful if someone could help me in how can I solve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is the monitor running at 30hz or 60hz?  In general, using HDMI for computer monitors is a profoundly bad idea.

Comment: It's running at 75hz. As the monitor has only HDMI output, how would you recommend connect it to the computer? Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I've read reports before of poor shielding on DVI, HDMI, and DP cables and adapters interfering with wireless devices before.  There's a few things I've seen reported as fixes, all focused on added shielding.

One cheap fix is to wrap the HDMI connector on the cable, and/or the HDMI adapter, in some kind of metal foil or tape.  Aluminum foil would work, the same kind commonly used to wrap food for cooking.  People have used metal tape, the kind used to repair HVAC duct work.  The tape option is the more durable option, and can make a mess if you try to peel it off, so look before you leap on this option.  This is often disliked by many as it is quite ugly but you can try this with some foil at least temporarily to test the theory.

One thing to try is a new HDMI cable.  This is not as cheap as wrapping the cable in aluminum foil but should still not hurt too much.  I've seen quality HDMI cables for about $8 from small brick-n-mortar shops and online.  Big box stores should have a cable with adequate shielding for under $25.  If a new cable doesn't fix it then you might need to get a new dongle or wrap the one you have in metal foil or tape, likely in addition to the new cable.

There could be something else going on but I'm thinking radio frequency interference from HDMI is the most likely cause.  Good luck on this.